# Solutions of: $P(x)=\displaystyle x^{2016}+(2016!+1!) x^{2015}+(2015!+2!) x^{2014}+ \cdots + (1!+2016!)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, parity

> Find the number of integer solution of the equation: $$\displaystyle x^{2016}+(2016!+1!) x^{2015}+(2015!+2!) x^{2014}+ \cdots + (1!+2016!)=0$$
>   where $n!=n \cdot (n-1) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$, for $n \geq1$

Please complete my proof:

Suppose $P(x)$ is any polynomial with integer coefficients and let it has a integer root, denoted by $a$, then
 $P(x)=(x-a)Q$. Now put $x=0$, then
$P(0)=-aQ$ and put $x=1$, then
$P(1)=(1-a)Q$. If we can prove $Q$ is even,
then we can say that among the above two $(P(0)$ and $P(1))$ one is even and the other is odd.
So let $$P(x)=\displaystyle x^{2016}+(2016!+1!) x^{2015}+(2015!+2!) x^{2014}+ \cdots + (1!+2016!)$$
clearly for $x=0,P(0)=2016!+1!$ which is an odd integer.
now put $x=1, P(1)=1+2(2016!+1!)+2(2015!+2!)+\cdots+2(1009!+1008!)=1+2(2016!+2015!+\cdots+2!+1!)$ which is an odd integer,so it is a contradiction!!
Thus,$$\displaystyle x^{2016}+(2016!+1!) x^{2015}+(2015!+2!) x^{2014}+ \cdots + (1!+2016!)=0$$ have no solutions.

But I can't prove $Q$ is not even, and point out where I'm lacking, please help for that.

Comment: There is a flaw in your argument: $Q$ is in fact a polynomial $Q(x)$, so after substitution you will get $P(0)=-aQ(0)$, and $P(1)=(1-a)Q(1)$, which does _not_ resemble the same $Q$. For this reason you will have to prove neither $Q(0)$ nor $Q(1)$ is even to conclude your proof.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Yes for that I'm looking for. $Q$ is not even. Is it not easy to prove? (if you can please add it here).

Comment: Well, the best reason for $Q$ not being even might be that $P(x)$ is never even. But such a reasoning is senseless, since $P(x)$ being never even just implies the desired result. So I would prefer a more direct way, as I've shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just recall that $x(x+1)$ is even for integer $x$, which implies $x^{2016}+x^{2015}=x^{2014}x(x+1)$ is even. And all $n!$, $n\ge 2$ is even, so is $2016!x^{2015}+(2015!+2!)x^{2014}+\ldots+(2!+2015!)x+2016!$  . We conclude by noting that $$P(x)=(x^{2016}+x^{2015})+\Big(2016!x^{2015}+(2015!+2!)x^{2014}+\ldots+(2!+2015!)x+2016!\Big)+1!\\
=\rm even + even + 1 = odd$$
hence is never $0$.

Comment: what you meant by $\rm LHS=1+some~even~number$? please add it in answer.

Comment: @Ayushakj I've edited the answer.